# How do you hash and salt passwords that are stored in SharedObjects in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, encryption, hash, cryptography

In AS3, how would I hash and salt passwords in that are stored in the SharedObject class?

```
var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("usernameInfo");

sharedObject.data.userName = "randomusername";
sharedObject.data.password= "randompassword";
sharedObject.flush();
```

Comment: doesn't matter how you hash them, if they are stored in sharedobject then it won't even take a hacker to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As3crypto library has several hashing functions:

https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/